# Inclusion of smooth maps implies smooth again

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\phi: N \to M$ be a continuous map from smooth manifold $N$ to smooth submanifold $M \subset \Bbb R^p$. Let $i :M \to \Bbb R^p$. Show that if $i \circ \phi$ is smooth, then so is $\phi$.

Isn't this trivially true because $i\circ \phi = \phi$? Or do I have to throw in the charts to make this firm? But I still think I'll be using $i \circ \phi =\phi$. So I don't know what the difference is.

**EDIT**: Because $i \circ \phi$ is smooth, there are charts $(f_i,U_i,U_i')$ with $i = 1,2$ where $U_1' \subset N$ and $U_2' \subset \Bbb R^p$ where $f_2 \circ i \circ \phi \circ f_1^{-1}$ is smooth. So $\phi = i^{-1} \circ f_2^{-1} \circ \psi \circ f_1$ where $\psi = f_2 \circ i \circ \phi \circ f_1^{-1}$. How do I get it in the form of "chart composed $\phi$ composed with another chart inverse"

Comment: But $\phi$ has codomain $M$ while $i \circ \phi$ has codomain $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Comment: @Titus, $\Bbb R^p$ is the codomain. The inclusion is bijective with $\phi(N)$ no?

Comment: Let me rephrase.  Lee's answer below points this out explicitly.  You determine the smoothness of a map by looking at coordinate charts on the domain and codomain; these charts will be different for $M$ and $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p \in N$ and $q = i\circ \phi(p) \in \mathbb{R}^p$.  Since $i \circ \phi$ is smooth, given a chart $(\psi, U)$ where $U$ is open and contains $p$, and a chart $(\psi', B(q))$ where $B(q)$ is an open ball about $q$ in $\mathbb{R}^p$, we have that 
$$\psi' \circ i \circ \phi \circ \psi^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{p}$$
is a smooth map in the usual sense.  Since $M$ is a *smooth submanifold* of $\mathbb{R}^p$, its charts are generated by the open sets $B_k \cap M$ (where the $B_k$ are open balls in the ambient euclidean space) and its maps $\psi_M'$, are also inherited from $\mathbb{R}^p$.

In particular, on $M$ the map $\psi'_M$ may be chosen so that $\psi'(B_k\cap M)$ maps points in $M$ onto a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^p$, say $\psi'(p_M) = (x_1,\dots,x_m,0,\dots,0)$.  Then $\psi'_M$ may be defined as 
$$\pi \circ \psi' \circ i$$ where $$\pi((x_1,\dots,x_m,0,\dots,0)) = (x_1,\dots,x_m).$$

Now

$$ \psi'_M \circ \phi \circ \psi^{-1} = \pi \circ \psi' \circ i \circ \phi \circ \psi^{-1}$$

and the right-hand side is smooth.

Comment: (I adopted Lee's usage of $n$ as the dimension of $N$.)

Comment: I get the gist of what you are doing. But isn't $\psi' : N \to \Bbb R^n$? The target is $\Bbb R^n$ because $\psi$ is a homeomoprhism (that's what it means to be a chart). Sorry for my stupid questions. (actually let me think about this more before you answer….)

Comment: Made some edits, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: The way I've set up the charts $\psi$ has domain $N$, $\psi'$ has domain $\mathbb{R}^p$, while $\psi'_M$ has domain $M$.

Comment: I am gonna assume you mean $p_M = \pi$?

Comment: Forgot that.  $p_M$ is just some point on $M$.  The map with it was wrong, it's been edited.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your notation for a chart; $\gamma$ is the map, are $U$ and $V$ domain and codomain?  I'm writing $m = dim(M)$ and the index $k$ is signifying the choice of ball: $\{ B_k \}_{k \in K}$ is my basis for the topology of $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Comment: Yes they were, I think my $U^m$ were your $B_k$s.

Comment: My original comment: *Okay so I think this is the rundown, correct me if I am wrong.My first question probably made no sense to you because I swapped $\psi$ and $\psi'$ in my picture. Anyways, because $M \subset \Bbb R^m \subset \Bbb R^p$ is a sub manifold, we have a chart $(\gamma, U, V)$ with $\gamma (U^m \cap M) = V^{m} \cap \Bbb R^m$ and I guess you called my $\gamma = \psi_M$. I think you also made a typo that the dimension of $B_K$ is $m$ not $k$. Unless your $k$ means something else here.*

Comment: $M$ is $m$-dimensional, not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$.  $\gamma$ should map from an open set in the manifold $\mathbb{R}^p$ to an open set in the manifold $M$.  I'm with you if $ \gamma(U^p \cap M) = V^m$ for some open $V \subset M$.  Superscripts denoting dimension.  Can you understand the post now?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that $M$ is $m$-dimensional and $N$ is $n$-dimensional.

The maps $i \circ \phi$ and $\phi$ are not equal because they have different ranges: the range of $\phi$ is the manifold $M$, whereas the range of $i \circ \phi$ is $\mathbb{R}^p$.

To prove that $\phi$ is smooth means that, when you express $\phi$ using coordinate charts on $M$ itself, the resulting maps between open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^m$ are smooth. The idea of the proof is that, from the implicit function theorem, one obtains coordinate charges for $M$ by restricting projection maps from $\mathbb{R}^p$ to $m$-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Comment: Sorry my initial idea is not right, can you lead me to the right direction from where I am now? I am guessing projection comes in for showing each component is smooth?